# PHP show final price using check boxes

Tags: php, ajax, post, cart

I am currently working on a search engine for my company. It uses AJAX and PHP, the search engine is done, but now I am facing another problem.

Is there any way to only post the prices for the articles that were ticked? This is the code so far:

```
<thead>
    <th class="col1">Codigo</th>
    <th class="col2">C&oacute;digo Cat&aacute;logo</th>
    <th class="col3">Descripci&oacute;n</th>
    <th class="col4">Precio </th>
    <th class="col5">Carrito</th>
    <th class="col6">Cantidad</th>  
</thead>
<td><?php echo $row['codigo']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['codigo_cat']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['descripcion']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['precio']; ?></td>
    <td><form action="cart.php" method="post"><input type='checkbox' name='buy[]' value='1' /></td>
    <td><input type="number" id="num"/><input type="submit" value="Calc"/>    </form></td>
```

Comment: Posting prices is useless, it needs to be calculated on the server side or it's easily hackable. Post the item ids instead. (unless that's not what you mean, in which case the question is more unclear thatn I originally thought)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not recommend that, how would you know what article was checked if there are multiple with the same price?

I would add the ID of the product so you know which one it is:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='buy[<?php echo $row['id']; ?>]' value='1' />
```

And your individual `form` tags that span multiple columns will not work (invalid html and every box is in another form). You should only have one form that spans the table.

Comment: Thank you, that helped, now, how can retrieve all of the buy+id on the PHP page with $_POST? I don't think adding each one individually would be optimal.

Comment: @user1574621 `$_POST['buy]` will be an array where the keys are your product id's and the values are 1.

Comment: Well, I have extracted the values using array_keys, and I can now print the numbers, but now when I do a query like "select * from table where id = $id" It goes wrong, for example, if the selected Id's are 1 and 42 it chooses the Id 142, any way to fix it?